# Failed to install AKS on Az Stack HCI

Tags: azure-aks, azure-stack

I try to install AKS on Azure stack HCI cluster but it stuck at Validating Load Balancer VIP, though my control-plane appliance is up and running.

this error shows at install-AksHci command

Comment: Could you please share the complete stack trace of the error message to understand your problem?

Comment: It was a problem in my network and i fix it. The connectivity to my AKS vlan was restricted.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable full traffic between Management host VLAN and AKS Vlan. I recommend to enable full internet access to those VLANs

Comment: Providing full internet access defeats the purpose of having controlled private networks. The documents should contain the needed network specifications